# submitting form with parameter from a link in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to save data in database in background through a link, and to give download functionality to that link in front end. but it gives an error.

my script is -

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#download").click(function(){
        var me = $(this), data = me.data('params');
        saveData(me);
});

function saveData(me){  
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "download_counter.php",
       data: { client_id: "<? echo $client_id;?>", candidate_id: me }
    });
}
});
</script>
```

this is the link (It looks fine)

```
<a href="upload/<? echo $download;?>" id="download" data-params="{'ca_id':'<? echo $ca_id;?>'}"><button name="download"></button></a>
```

download_counter.php looks like -

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['candidate_id'])) { // Form has been submitted.
    $candidate_id = $_POST['candidate_id'];
    $client_id= $_POST['client_id'];
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    echo "client - ".$client_id;
    echo "candidate - ".$candidate_id;
    $query = "INSERT INTO `downloads`(`client_id`, `candidate_id`, `download_date`) VALUES ('".$client_id."', '".$candidate_id."', '".$date."')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);  
}
?>
```

when i click the link, it lets download the file but database do not updates.
Please help.

Comment: It's most likely because the browser cancels the AJAX request because the user is sent to a new page (the download). One way would be to do `e.preventDefault()` in the onclick function (add the e argument), and then redirect the user when the ajax is done. Or create a redirect page in php that counts then redirects to the download. This will count for users without JS as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error with passing parameter to function saveData, so your ajax request not occur:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#download").click(function(){
        var me = $(this), data = me.data('params');
        saveData(data); // was me
});
```

Comment: query is running, but database is not updating yet. :(

Comment: there might me issue with escaping the variable values, check this link -- [`escaping and passing php variables to sql insert query`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-insert-statement)`

Comment: yes. database is updating now with your suggestion. but it is not getting value of candidate_id..  i am doing this  -   $("#download").click(function(){  
  $("#count").hide();
  var me = $(this), data = me.data('params');
        saveData(data); // was me                                                   type: "POST",
    url: "counter.php",
    data: { client_id: "2", candidate_id: data.ca_id }

Comment: yes because php have an array in variable $_POST['candidate_id']. In your case you don't need to have link with array in data parameter: data-params="{'ca_id':'<? echo $ca_id;?>'}" but only data-caid="<? echo $ca_id;?>" and in js $(..).data('caid');

Answer (score 0):

Check jquery [click event handler](http://api.jquery.com/click/), which says

```
// say your selector and click handler is somewhat as in the example
$("some selector").click({param1: "Hello", param2: "World"}, some_function);

// then in the called function, grab the event object and use the parameters like this--
function some_function(event){
    alert(event.data.param1);
    alert(event.data.param2);
}
```

Comment: what is this param1 and param2. i want to get values from my link. how to do that

Answer (score 0):

database is updating now, but it is not getting value of candidate_id.

i did this -

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#download").click(function(){        
        $("#count").hide();
        var me = $(this), data = me.data('params');
        saveData(data); // was me
});

function saveData(data){  
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "counter.php",
       data: { client_id: "2", candidate_id: data.ca_id }
    });
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: please console.log the `data` in the saveData function and paste it over here.

Comment: what is that Anil? And how to do that..?

Comment: i am talking about `console.log()` function, it will log the passed parameter to console. So what i want you to do is in the saveData function just before $.ajax({---}); write `console.log(data);` then see what is logged in console and paste that output.

Comment: i did it. but where is this console..?

Comment: open your link in chrome and press key `F12`.

Comment: i have added an answer, please go through that, it might solve your problem.

Comment: `1113-10y-Far-32` this is the data which is get printed in console. That's what i wanted, and code running fine tooo.

Comment: can you help me a little here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511793/error-with-draggable-and-droppable-image

Answer (score 0):

```
I think on click the data you are reading is a string and in the given format. 
And you are passing that as data, but since it is not an valid id, 
that value in the database is not updated.
```

[Check this out](http://jsfiddle.net/TQ6Lu/)